# The best delimiter to explode/implode a text string - @, !, <>, # or |

Tags: php, mysql, delimiter, explode

Suppose the text doesn't contain special symbols (doesn't contain @,!, <>, #, | etc).

I've read [PHP Delimiters manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and the answer from there

```
Anonymous
other possible delimiters include @,!, <>
using symbols (such as | ) that have meaning inside a regex as delimiters is probably going to be counterproductive.
```

So, what symbol(s) would you use as a delimiter for the text to store the text in one cell of mysql table?
The explanation with pros and cons is much appreciated.

Comment: I imagine it depends on your situation, what type of data are you delimiting?

Comment: I don’t quite understand your question. Both `explode` and `implode` don’t work with regular expressions but with plain strings. So what do you use the delimiter for?

Comment: I agree with @Gumbo. If your text doesn't contain any of the special symbols then there is no difference which one you choose to separate your strings since the separator will be removed with the explode anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to saving a list to a database in a single text cell, I go for either serialization or use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I use `|` or `. First one can be used if you are not planning to store REGEX. Basically, every rare symbol is good, and combinations of them (`|||`) will work even better.

Keep in mind that explode is only 3 times faster than json_decode (0.000002066 vs 0.000006676, [source](https://wyman.blog/unserialize-performance-php/)), which is very fast by itself. So encoding in JSON is probably much better.